# WebDriver getText() not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have selected this td using find by CSS selector (I have used firepath, it definitely selects this td element). It is stored in a WebElement called newEntry.

```
<td>
06003d49-33d5-4aeb-bfe6-c2da3e686bac
<span id="absenceTypeform:abstable:0:absenceTypeBeanDescMsg"></span>
<input id="absenceTypeform:abstable:0:j_idt105" class="edit-row hidden" type="submit" 
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@all','absenceTypeform:absenceTypediv',{'onevent':displayEditControlCallback});return false" 
value="Edit" name="absenceTypeform:abstable:0:j_idt105">
</td>
```

If I then do

```
System.out.println("Text of new Entry " + newEntry.getText());
```

I am expecting it to print the '06003d49-33d5-4aeb-bfe6-c2da3e686bac' which is the text inside the td element. But the result of the print is simply 'Text of new Entry' with nothing appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

With the current HTML code, you won't be able to get the value in your script using `getText()`

you can use javascript **childNodes** to get the text from the nodes

**Below is an example in java**

Don't forget to add return since you need to return the value to the caller

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='absenceTypeform:abstable:0:absenceTypeBeanDescMsg']/ancestor::td"));

String expectedresult = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue",element);

System.out.println("expectedresult is "+expectedresult.trim());
```

I tried with the above code it was working fine

Hope this helps you...kindly get back if you have any doubts